# Sacar los mayores valores de un count SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

tengo esta consulta "Mostrar id y nombre de la/s instalación/es que albergaron más eventos el año pasado.". Como me pide de las instalaciones, refiere a que si la cantidad de eventos máximo fue 10 y hay dos instalaciones que tienen 10 entonces que me muestre ambas dos.
Hasta ahora hice esto pero solo me devuelve el primer valor, con TOP no creo que sea la solución ya que si lo uso debería poner un limite y la idea es que siempre muestre las instalaciones con más eventos sin importar cuantas sean.

```
Instalacion(idInstalac,nomInstalac)
Eventos(idEvento,idInstalac)
```

```
SELECT MAX(idInstalac), MAX(cantidadIns)  
FROM  (SELECT E.idInstalac, COUNT(*) as cantidadIns  
        FROM Eventos E INNER JOIN Instalacion I ON I.idInstalac = E.idInstalac  
        WHERE YEAR(fchEvento) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1  
        GROUP BY E.idInstalac) C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu versión de SQL Server lo permite, una forma podría ser usando [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) en una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) o en su defecto una subconsulta, para numerar cada grupo según la cantidad, y luego simplemente filtramos el grupo 1 (los casos máximos)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  E.idInstalac, 
            COUNT(*) as cantidadIns,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) desc) AS RN
            FROM Eventos E 
            INNER JOIN Instalacion I 
            ON I.idInstalac = E.idInstalac  
            WHERE YEAR(fchEvento) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1  
            GROUP BY E.idInstalac
)
SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar having en el group by para establecer este criterio, a los valores agrupados.

```
SELECT E.idInstalac
     , COUNT(*) as cantidadIns  
FROM Eventos E 
     INNER JOIN Instalacion I ON I.idInstalac = E.idInstalac  
WHERE YEAR(fchEvento) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1  
GROUP BY E.idInstalac
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

[Having](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: No, porque ahí estoy filtrando para los que sean mayor a 10 (este fue solo un ejemplo). Yo siempre quiero mostrar el mayor o los mayores sin importar la cantidad.